# Add markers on map (json) using leaflet and D3

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js, leaflet

I've adapted Mike Bostock's original D3 + Leaflet example: http://bost.ocks.org/mike/leaflet/ so I would like to add markers on my map using this code. But not possible, certainly a small rookie mistake. thank you

```
var LeafIcon = L.Icon.extend({
options: {
iconSize:     [38,60],
iconAnchor:   [19,45],
popupAnchor:  [-3, -76]
}
});
var fIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_f.png'}),
rIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_r.png'}),
pIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_p.png'}),
vIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_v.png'}),
jIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_j.png'}),
ggIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_gg.png'});
L.marker([48.21,-4.46], {icon: fIcon}).bindPopup("<h2>Crozon</h2><br>").addTo(map);
L.marker([48.37,-4.49], {icon: cIcon}).bindPopup("Jetee").addTo(map);
```

Comment: where did you define `cIcon`? It's giving me "variable not found"...

Comment: I deleted that line to save space
cIcon = new LeafIcon({iconUrl: 'puce_c.png'}),
I believe that the proble come on with addTo(map) ?

Comment: Are you sure that these coordinates are what you are looking for? They are in Europe... (I live pretty close, so I'm sure about that ;-))

Comment: my original map with leaflet and map box
(http://meteohotline.com/webdev/essai_mapbox_pb.html)
and the same map with Mike Bostok that I want to use with L.marker
(http://meteohotline.com/webdev/world_d3_leaflet.html)

Comment: OK I found the solution , 
it's not beautiful, but it works.

Comment: If it is helpful to others, please consider submitting an answer yourself. This way this question does not stay "unanswered", if someone else has the same problem.

Comment: My little solution : 
http://meteohotline.com/webdev/leaflet_d3_json.html